# App for mac that automatically rearranges apps when I plug in to an external monitor

Tags: mac, display, window-manager

I'm looking for an app for my mac that automatically rearranges apps when I plug in to an external monitor.

An app that let's me arrange windows in certain positions and save them as configurations that I can select later to reposition them.

Something a lot like [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay) (I've tried in the past) but with multiple named configurations that I could apply. Stay also doesn't work with Adobe's Create Suite of tools.

Comment: @Allan Somewhat of a duplicate, but the title of that question is not so good and the circumstances there are pretty specific. Also this OP has requirements not satisfied by *Stay*. I think this one should be open.

Comment: There's a much better dupe somewhere, with lots of alternatives... I'm hunting...